# Which is best architecture and design pattern for flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, design-patterns, architecture

I decided start to learn architecture and design patter for flutter. I've little bite confusion, which architecture is best practice to learn. Because some architecture is there in this plaform like Flutter Bloc Pattern (Business Logic Component), MVVM, MVC,... so on. Anyone help, how to choose which is best one.

I decided to be work flutter project for self taught purpose. Any suggestion

Comment: If you've no prior knowledge about design pattern. Then start simple with MVC and provider for state management. As you grasp the basic concepts you can move to MVVM, Bloc, Riverpod etc.

Comment: Yes, I decided to move clean architecture with MVVM

Answer (score 1):

I can say Bloc, provider, riverPod are good as mentioned order. (based on my experience)